# Check json field from the curl response in linux

Tags: linux, gitlab-ci, alpine-linux

I am writing a script in gitlab-ci file and the server I am using is Linux to run the pipeline.

Now I want to make two API call and 2nd call is dependent on the 1st

for example

`URL= you can take any HTTPS endpoint (i guess it really doesn't matter)`

`jsonResponse=$(curl -d $requestJson -X POST $FIRST_URL)`

`echo $jsonResponse`

`[{"result":"Success"}]`

Based on the result field (success/failure) I want to make another API call using curl. something like below

`if response[0].result=success then "curl -d $requestJson -X POST $SECOND_URL" else exit 1`

*Note that the response will be in Array.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could possibly do is that you will save the output from 1st API call to a file (api1-output.json) and then pass it to the next correspondent job from where you can read that output and act based on its response.

Example in your ***.gitlab-ci.yml*** file:

```
api1_execution:
   image: your_image
   script:
      - curl -XGET https://my-api1-endpoint.com/api/getSomething > scripts/api1-output.json
   artifacts:
      paths:
         - scripts/api1-output.json


api2_execution:
   image: your_image
   script:
      - API1_OUTPUT= $(cat scripts/api1-output.json)
      - // do whatherever you want with API1_OUTPUT
      - // fire 2nd API call
```

For parsing and reading JSON output I highly recommend that you use tool called [jQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

The above example can serve to you just as an idea how it can be done from my perspective.

Comment: jQ tools helps to extract the details and it worked, Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

> I want to make two rest API call and 2nd rest call is dependent on the 1st response

#### Please reason in terms of protocols: so [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) (or [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)) and [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer). Read much more about both of them.

You could use some existing [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) library (e.g. [jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) in C, or [jsoncpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) in C++) and combine them with some HTTP client library (e.g. [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)) and/or HTTP server library (e.g. [libonion](https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion)).

You might be interested by existing C++ frameworks such as [Qt](https://qt.io/) or [POCO](https://pocoproject.%20org/).

You should look at recent language implementations, such as [Go](https://go-lang.org/) or [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) or [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/) or [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/) or [Node.JS](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/). They provide useful libraries (related to HTTP and REST, both client and server side).

You might consider using scripting languages like [Python](https://python.org/) or [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/guile.html) or [Lua](https://lua.org/) or [Perl](https://www.perl.org/) or [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/), etc..... They also have relevant libraries for your needs.

#### Read the documentation of the programming languages implementations and libraries you want to use.

I tend to believe that [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) is not the best alternative for your needs (consider also at least GNU [gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/)).

Look also on both [github](https://github.com/) and [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/) for [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) implementations relevant to your needs. Once these are specified (perhaps using [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) notation for the messages you want to implement; read also about [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) and [JSONRPC](https://jsonrpc.org/)) on paper, the implementation is fairly easy.

Be sure to read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [sockets(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sockets.7.html).

> What will correct way to validate the field

#### First, specify on paper what are valid fields.

Also, write several examples of valid fields, and of invalid fields. Then consider using [regex(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html). Also **study** for inspiration **the source code of *existing* open source software similar to your needs**.

See also [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/411181/40065).

Comment: updated my question. let me know if you understood what i am trying to say

Comment: My answer above still stands and answers your question

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am also puzzled how your answer is related to the question that Anand Kumar asked?